# Android View position not updating after ObjectAnimator tranlation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I've got 3 equally-spaced ImageViews (A,B and C) laid out horizontally across the screen. When an ImageView is clicked, it slides across the screen to the left (to the position of A) and the other two disappear. If A is the one that's clicked, then the other two just disappear.

Once the translation is complete, the translated ImageView is assigned new click behavior. When it's clicked now, it returns to its original position (and the unclicked ImageViews re-appear).

I'm using **ObjectAnimator** to do the translation and I'm using a single pre-computed value in order to determine how far a clicked ImageView should travel. This value is the pixel distance between the left-most edge of each ImageView and it's neighbor. When the first click is detected, the ImageView is animated like this:

```
ObjectAnimator posterSlider = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            imageView, "translationX", -imageViewIdx * slideDistance);
```

So, in the case of A, the ImageViews index position in the parent will be 0, which when multipled by the slide distance will still be 0, so it never moves. If the index position is 1, the slide distance will be -slideDisance etc. And it works fine.

The problem is that when the ImageView is returning to it's original position after being clicked a second time, the translated position is not correct. The translation code is simply the same as above, except instead of `-imageViewIdx * slideDistance` it becomes `imageViewIdx * slideDistance`. In the case of **B** returning to its original position, it actually returns to the position of **C**. In the case of **C** returning to its original position, it goes off the screen to the right. **A** works fine, but that's just a fluke, because it never has to move at all.

So it's apparent that when determining the ImageViews return position, the **ObjectAnimator** is adding the `slideDistance` onto the ImageViews *original starting* position, and not the new position after the first click, like I would expect.

Is there something that I need to do with **ObjectAnimator** or a layout after an animation to force it to update a views position? Remember, after the first translation, the ImageViews new click behavior works fine, so there's no problem detecting the new position with that. Also, when I log the ImageViews X coordinate after the first translation using `imageView.getX()` it reports the correct position (the left side of the screen) like I would expect.

I'm targeting min API 16. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How do you make those two views disappear? If you add `0` to the revert animation in the `ObjectAnimator`(before `imageViewIdx * slideDistance`) the behavior persists?

Comment: The two unclicked views have their alpha values animated to 0, and when those animations end, their alpha values are set to 0. I tried adding in a 0 like you suggested. The problem persists, but before the revert animation starts, the ImageView jumps to its original position and then the animation starts.

Comment: OK, so it's working now. I just had to replace the imageViewIdx*slideDistance in the revert with 0. So it seems that the ObjectAnimator always considers it's starting position to be 0, and knows that 0 = [original position for that view]. That's convenient, but not what I was expecting. Thanks for for putting me on the right track @Luksprog

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to use:

```
ObjectAnimator posterSlider = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationX", 0);
```

...for the return animation. It seems that a view "remembers" its original position after a translation. So, passing 0 as the destination to the ObjectAnimator is the same as saying "send the view back to it's original position".

Answer (score 4):

The assumption that you had in your code is that the ObjectAnimator will change the value of `translationX` by `imageViewIdx * slideDistance`.

Actually ObjectAnimator will change the value of `translationX` to `imageViewIdx * slideDistance`.

```
Initial State -
Left = XYZ (say)
TranslationX = 0
X = Left + TranslationX = XYZ

After 1st Click -
Left = XYZ
TranslationX = -(imageViewIdx * slideDistance)
X = Left + TranslationX = XYZ - (imageViewIdx * slideDistance)

After 2nd Click -
Left = XYZ
Translation X = imageViewIdx * slideDistance
X = Left + TranslationX = XYZ + (imageViewIdx * slideDistance)
```

Therefore the fix that you yourself recommended, to set the translationX to 0 is correct. But the reasoning was incorrect.

Hope this clarifies the doubt.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could find `reverse()` method inherited from `ValueAnimator` class useful.